# How do I convince a team of 'developers' how bad this is?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-injection

No matter how hard I try, I cant convince others here how bad and wrong code like this is. Some comments would be nice.

```
def addStudentToClass
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.insert("INSERT INTO student_class (student_id, class_id, creator_id, created_at) VALUES (#{params[:student_id]}, #{params[:class_id]}, (SELECT creator_id FROM classes WHERE class_id = #{params[:class_id]}), NOW())")
 usrObj = User.find(params[:student_id]).load_goal_structures();
 render json: nil
end
```

Any constructive comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"Please enjoy the comment functionality to explain how bad this is"*. You're doing SO wrong.

Comment: Really should be either on programmers or codereview or nowhere.

Comment: Ok sorry. Didnt mean to do wrong. What is the best way then?

Comment: Send in '/whateverpath?student_id=";DROP DATABASE;'

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Ah, little Bobby Tables.

Comment: This code suggests that you have a model called `Class`. You might encounter some problems there..

Comment: I know SQL is by far the worst thing here but Class is jut another one, just like anything else, honestly. If you look at the code snippet you can find at least 5 things breaking conventions, best practices, security, etc.

Comment: The code is too ugly to have any comment.

Answer (score 14):

It shouldn't be hard.  Show them this [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/) and if they still don't get it, start looking for another job.

Comment: Ahahahahah! This is where the "Little Bobby Tables" comes from!